# Does virtual address matching matter in shared mem IPC?

Tags: caching, cpu, shared-memory, x86-64

I'm implementing IPC between two processes on the same machine (Linux x86_64 shmget and friends), and I'm trying to maximize the throughput of the data between the processes: for example I have restricted the two processes to only run on the same CPU, so as to take advantage of hardware caching.

My question is, does it matter where in the virtual address space each process puts the shared object?  For example would it be advantageous to map the object to the same location in both processes?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter as long as the OS is concerned. It would have been advantageous to use the same base address in both processes if the TLB cache wasn't flushed between context switches. The Translation Lookaside Buffer (TLB) cache is a small buffer that caches virtual to physical address translations for individual pages in order to reduce the number of expensive memory reads from the process page table. Whenever a context switch occurs, the TLB cache is flushed - you don't want processes to be able to read a small portion of the memory of other processes, just because its page table entries are still cached in the TLB.

Context switch does not occur between processes running on different cores. But then each core has its own TLB cache and its content is completely uncorrelated with the content of the TLB cache of the other core. TLB flush does not occur when switching between threads from the same process. But threads share their whole virtual address space nevertheless.

It only makes sense to attach the shared memory segment at the same virtual address if you pass around absolute pointers to areas inside it. Imagine, for example, a linked list structure in shared memory. The usual practice is to use offsets from the beginning of the block instead of aboslute pointers. But this is slower as it involves additional pointer arithmetic. That's why you might get better performance with absolute pointers, but finding a suitable place in the virtual address space of both processes might not be an easy task (at least not doing it in a portable way), even on platforms with vast VA spaces like x86-64.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert here, but seeing as there are no other answers I will give it a go.  I don't think it will really make a difference, because the virutal address does not necessarily correspond to the physical address.  Said another way, the underlying physical address the OS maps your virtual address to is not dependent on the virtual address the OS gives you.

Again, I'm not a memory master. Sorry if I am way off here.